# Two errors in my code

Tags: google-sheets

I want  to copy and paste the active row into another sheet but its giving me two errors:

1. Its not recognizing my input values.
2. Its not pasting any data and saying `copyTo` not found.

   ```
   function Anunaki() {  
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var sheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("KEY WORK");
       var sheetTwo = ss.getSheetByName("BUGS");
       var j = sheetTwo.getLastRow() + 1;
       var data = sheetOne.getActiveRange().getValues();
       var columnCount = data[0].length
       var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

       var response = ui.prompt('BUG Confirmation', 'How many Interactions ?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

       if (response === "0")   
       {
           ui.alert('Opps Zero I don\'t believe you, Try again');
       }
       else if (response === "1")
       {
           sheetOne.getRange(1,1,1,columnCount).copyTo(sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount));
       }
       else if (response === "2" ) 
       {
           sheetOne.getRange(1,1,1,columnCount).copyTo(sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount));
       }
       else 
       {
           ui.alert('Please enter a numeric value between 1 to 2');
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following line in your code:

```
var response = ui.prompt('BUG Confirmation', 'How many Interactions ?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
```

To:

```
var response = ui.prompt('BUG Confirmation', 'How many Interactions ?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO).getResponseText();
```

===============
Edited:
Following is the complete code that should work:

```
  function Anunaki() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("KEY WORK");
  var sheetTwo = ss.getSheetByName("BUGS");

  if( ss.getActiveSheet().getName() != sheetOne.getName() )
  return;

  var j = sheetTwo.getLastRow() + 1;
  var data = sheetOne.getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = sheetOne.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var columnCount = data[0].length
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response = ui.prompt('BUG Confirmation', 'How many Interactions ?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO).getResponseText();

  if (response === "0") {
    ui.alert('Opps Zero I don\'t believe you, Try again');
  }

  else if (response === "1") {
    sheetOne.getRange(row,1,1,columnCount).copyTo(sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount));
  }

  else if (response === "2" ) {
    sheetOne.getRange(row,1,1,columnCount).copyTo(sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount));
  }
  else {
    ui.alert('Please enter a numeric value between 1 to 2');
  }

};
```

**NOTE:**
I have added 'var row' in the script to get the current row which needs to used in getRange function to get the values of entire row range.

**Edit:** To get only values and not the formula in the destination sheet, try the following code:

```
function Anunaki() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("KEY WORK");
  var sheetTwo = ss.getSheetByName("BUGS");

  if( ss.getActiveSheet().getName() != sheetOne.getName() )
  return;

  var j = sheetTwo.getLastRow() + 1;
  var data = sheetOne.getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = sheetOne.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var columnCount = data[0].length
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response = ui.prompt('BUG Confirmation', 'How many Interactions ?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO).getResponseText();

  if (response === "0") {
    ui.alert('Opps Zero I don\'t believe you, Try again');
  }

  else if (response === "1") {
    var values = sheetOne.getRange(row,1,1,columnCount).getValues();
    sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount).setValues(values)
  }

  else if (response === "2" ) {
    var values = sheetOne.getRange(row,1,1,columnCount).getValues();
    sheetTwo.getRange(j,1,1,columnCount).setValues(values)
  }
  else {
    ui.alert('Please enter a numeric value between 1 to 2');
  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: ji Now i have another problem, Its not taking  data from the cell and pasting it to another sheet. its giving this error "Cannot find function copyTo in object"

Comment: It is not much clear with your code, what exactly are you trying to copy?

Comment: ok I am trying to copy only value not formula of the entire row of the active cell to another sheet. note it should not overlap the data in second sheet if i run the script for second time.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check it out, the script code should now work as you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort kishan. I dont want to sound greedy but I just wanted to paste values only not formula. this is pasting the formula as well.

Comment: Ok i have done it by adding {contentsOnly:true} thanks again